# Repeat each value of an array two times (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let `A` be a numpy array like :

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I want to find the cleaner way to produce a new array with each value repeated two times:

```
B = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
```

**Do you think this is the simpler way to do it ?**

```
import numpy as np
B = np.tile(A,2).reshape(2,-1).flatten('F')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.column_stack` and `numpy.ndarray.flatten`:

```
In [12]: numpy.column_stack((A, A)).flatten()                                                    
Out[12]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
In [27]: A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*1000)                                                   

In [28]: %timeit numpy.column_stack((A, A)).flatten()                                            
10000 loops, best of 3: 44.7 µs per loop                                                         

In [29]: %timeit numpy.repeat(A, 2)                                                              
10000 loops, best of 3: 104 µs per loop                                                          

In [30]: %timeit numpy.tile(A,2).reshape(2,-1).flatten('F')                                      
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the timing comparison. Could you also paste the full code for this timing comparison? (with `import timeit`, etc.)

Comment: @Basj That's the whole code :), I used [IPython shell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/shell.html) for this. You can also try it online: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/

Comment: Don't know why but I get a different timing order (for an x10 size A):

In [19]: %timeit numpy.column_stack((A, A)).flatten()                                            
1000 loops, best of 3: 657 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit numpy.tile(A,2).reshape(2,-1).flatten('F')                                      
1000 loops, best of 3: 574 us per loop

Comment: I actually get: repeat 1.42 us, column_stack 4.66 us and tile 9.09 us

Answer (score 11):

Use [repeat()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [3]: np.repeat(A,2)
Out[3]: array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this operation in a time critical region, the following code is the fastest (using Numpy 1.9 development version):

```
In [1]: A = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*1000) 
In [2]: %timeit numpy.array([A, A]).T.ravel('F')
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.44 µs per loop
```

Note that flatten would make an additional copy, so ravel should be used instead.

If you prefer readability, the column_stack and repeat functions are better:

```
In [3]: %timeit numpy.column_stack((A, A)).ravel()
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop

In [4]: timeit numpy.repeat(A, 2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 53.9 µs per loop
```